# Why does Spark fail with "value rdf is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdf, turtle-rdf, sansa

I am trying to use [SANSA-RDF](https://github.com/SANSA-Stack/SANSA-RDF) for reading turtle RDF files into Spark and create a graph. I am getting an error when I execute the following code. What am I missing?

```
    import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory
    import org.apache.jena.riot.Lang
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io.rdf._
    import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io._
    import scala.io.Source

    object SparkExecutor {
      private var ss:SparkSession = null

      def ConfigureSpark(): Unit ={

        ss = SparkSession.builder
          .master("local[*]")
          .config("spark.driver.cores", 1)
          .appName("LAM")
          .getOrCreate()

      }

      def createGraph(): Unit ={
        val filename = "xyz.ttl"
        print("Loading graph from file"+ filename)
        val lang = Lang.TTL
        val triples = ss.rdf(lang)(filename)
        val graph = LoadGraph(triples)    
      }
    }
```

I am calling the SparkExecutor from main function using

```
    object main {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        SparkExecutor.ConfigureSpark()
        val RDFGraph = SparkExecutor.createGraph()
      }
    }
```

This results in the following error

```
    Error: value rdf is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val triples = ss.rdf(lang)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a SNAPSHOT version if there is no good reason for doing so - a package was moved, as already explained in the answer below.

Comment: You have to remove `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` line i guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well there is an implicit conversion, if you see the SANSA-RDF source code in

```
sansa-rdf-spark/src/main/scala/net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/package.scala:159
```

rdf(lang) is not a method of spark session, but of implicit class RDFReader, so you need to import the package where the implicit definition is available. Please try adding

> import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io._

and let us know the result.

Comment: That's correct, a Scala package object was moved - clearly, this is change was done in the SNAPSHOT version, documentation will be updated in the next release.

Comment: @shuvomiah, thank you for the suggestion. I have added the import as you suggested. I am still getting the same error. I am working with Intellij. It seems as if Intellij is not recognising the import (gray in colour). I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: actually I pulled the latest code from github. Can you please search for the rdf method from RDFReader, and see in which package the class is declared ? It's definitely not an Intellij issue. Let us know.

Comment: @shuvomiah, thank you for the response.  The rdf method from RDFReader is defined in the package you mentioned **net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io**

Comment: I pulled the code from GitHub now and built a local jar. I included this in the libraries and now my code works fine. I am sure its a bad way of solving the problem.

Comment: @sukanyanath One more, time: don't use a SNAPSHOT dependency of this API, use the latest stable release. Or what's the reason for using the SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @AKSW, Thank you for the response. I am not sure I understand you correctly. I am using the version **SANSA RDF Spark Bundle 0.3.0**. Do you suggest another version?

Comment: @sukanyanath Great to know that. Can you please accept that as an answer ?

Comment: @sukanyanath In version 0.3.0 the package class is still `net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io.rdf`, thus, it works as expected. I don't know how you use the SANSA RDF API and which version.